# BCNF and 3NF property

Tags: database, normalization, rdbms, functional-dependencies

I read a statement that " If a relation is in 3NF and does not contain any overlapping candidate key then it is definitely in BCNF"

Suppose we consider a relation R(A,B,C,D) with following functional dependencies:-

AB --> CD

C --> A

Here only candidate key is AB and the resulting relation is in 3NF and not in BCNF because C is not a super key.
So the above statement doesn't hold true.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: AB isn't the only candidate key, BC is one too

Comment: Yeah, my bad :( . Can you give a proof for the statement if possible ? Some how it doesn't seem intuitive to me.

Comment: We do not reason by intuition, we apply definitions & algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relation has overlapping candidate keys. While it doesn't appear on the left-hand side of the given functional dependencies, we can derive the fact that BC is a candidate key.

Starting with C -> A, we can use Armstrong's Axiom of Augmentation to determine that CB -> AB, and since it's known that AB is a candidate key, that means all other attributes are determined.

Comment: I have one more doubt. Can a non prime attribute ever derive a prime attribute ? Like non-prime --> prime attribute . If no, then why ?

Comment: I think not, since for any candidate key with n attributes A1..An and functional dependency B -> Ax, B can take the place of Ax to produce another candidate key, making B prime as well.

Comment: Note that if B determined multiple attributes in candidate key A1..An then all of the determined prime attributes would have to be replaced with a single B for the result to be a candidate key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if RHS is set of prime attributes, LHS should also be set of prime attributes right ?

Comment: It doesn't hold in general for sets of attributes on the LHS. Consider R(A,B,C) with B -> AC and ABC -> B. B is a candidate key, ABC is a superkey and ABC -> B is trivially true, but ABC is not a candidate key.